# Curl produces different results when invoked via systemd vs command line

Tags: systemd, curl, discord

I have the following unit file:

```
[Unit]
Description=Sends a message to a discord channel

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=curl --header "Content-Type: application/json" --request POST --data '{"content":"MESSAGE TEXT HERE"}' https://discord.com/api/webhooks/WEBHOOK_ID_HERE/WEBHOOK_TOKEN_HERE
DynamicUser=yes

# No [Install] since this is meant to be used with a timer
```

Running the curl command that is in ExecStart manually posts the message to the Discord channel that corresponds to this webhook, while starting the service produces the response `{"code": 50109, "message": "The request body contains invalid JSON."}` from the Discord server.

Is there any notable difference between running a command through systemd and directly? For example, I could not find any indication that there might be a maximum command length for ExecStart.

Comment: I'd check if this affects the service: https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.syntax.html#Quoting

Answer (score 1):

Solved. Thanks to [A.B's comment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/740172/curl-produces-different-results-when-invoked-via-systemd-vs-command-line#comment1405673_740172) I realized I had `\n`s in the message, and as it turns out systemd interprets them before executing the command. Escaping the slashes (`\\n`) solved this and now it works.